# Core Data - Disable loading from cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, core-data, watchkit

I am working on a WatchKit Extension with using CoreData.

The CoreData StoreURL is the same like in the iOS App.
Within the iOS App it's working like expected.

1. I start the Watch-App in the Simulator.
2. I change some data in the iOS App.
3. The Watch-App is still loading the old data.

In the SQLite-File (which is used by both (App + WK-Extension)) there is the new data.
So it seems that CoreData in the WatchKit-Extension is fetching the data from a cache.

How can I disable the cache or force loading the new data?

This is how I fetch the Data:

```
- (NSArray*)fetchAllActive:(NSError**)error
{
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [super fetchRequestForTemplate:@"AllActiveReminder" substitutionVariables:nil];
    NSArray* result = [super fetchWithRequest:fetchRequest error:error];
    return result;
}
```

A call of `[managedObjectContext refreshObject: mergeChanges:]` does only working in a for-loop for the WKTable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came across the same problem when creating an Action extension that shared a Core Data store with it's containing app.  The solution that I came across that works for me is to set the stalenessInterval on the Main Queue NSManagedObjectContext as follows inside of your extension:

```
objectContext.stalenessInterval = 0.0;
```

This tells the context in the extension to fetch new data every time and ignore the cache.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it.
A `[managedObjectContext reset]` before a fetch does also work.

Comment: World would collapse without Stackoverflow. Worked for me too.